# Need a create list item example using spfx pnp

Tags: spfx-webparts, splistitem, pnpjs, office-ui-fabric-react

Having not touched spfx for sometime, I’m trying to find an example of creating a list item with a people picker a date picker and textfields but have not been able to find a working example. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Check: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

Comment: Thanks do you know where I can find a template for setting up pnpjs?